# Excel 2016 Pivot Table Sorting Dates Alphabetically

Tags: excel, pivot-table

This probably wouldn't count as a programming question, but I'm starting to think it might be a glitch with Microsoft Excel 2016.

My Pivot Table aren't sorting my dates chronologically.

When I toggle the 'Sort Oldest to Newest' in the pivot table, my dates seem to be sorted alphabetically.

```
Date Revenue
10-Aug $83,004
10-Nov $43,137
10-Oct $881,775
10-Sep $470,486
11-Aug $45,676
11-Nov $250,890
11-Oct $1,324,366
```

My source data is sorted chronologically no problem.

Source Data sorted nicely:

[image]

I have confirmed that my source dates are formatted as Date as well as the format in pivot table. However, I should note, that I can't seem to change the format of the dates on the pivot table. I've Tried the Following:

Opening the 'Value Field Settings Box' by right clicking on the 'Date' field in the Rows > Opening the Format Cells by clicking on 'Number Format' > Selecting Date (and changing the settings from 'd-month' }} This doesn't change the formatting
Highlighting the date column and changing the format to short date in the Number Section of the Home Ribbon }} this also doesn't change the format of the date

In order to confirm that my dates in my source information are formatted as dates, I used the 'Text to Columns' function to be sure that all the dates were pasted as mdy dates. I've also selected the column of dates and right clicked to access format cells as dates. Lastly, I ensured that they registered as dates according to the Number column in the home ribbon.

I thought this was a simple problem, I want my dates in my pivot table to sort chronologically, but it seems to be impossible.

[Here](http://www.filedropper.com/11-17-15dailyreport-troubleshootingversion) is a link to the file for reference.

Comment: If you have grouped the dates, they will get converted to text strings.

Comment: Is there a way to convert them back to to dates?

Comment: Indeed, looking at your file, all of the dates in the tables, except for the `Consolidated Data Sheet` are text and not "real dates".  I cannot access the Pivot tools on the workbook you uploaded (I have an earlier version of Excel than you), so can't really test anything.

Comment: try to help but it seems that the link to your file is broken...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3j936GAmQiSQk1JNVBXUjN3aFk

It seems that if I redo the entire workbook, the tables will sort correctly. It's bizarre though that there's nothing I can do to get the current pivot tables to sort chronologically.